# How to scan in DynamoDB without primary sort key with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to scan in DynamoDB without primary sort key with Nodejs.
I have the following Table

```
var params = {
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        {
        AttributeName: "barname",
        AttributeType: "S"
        },
        {
        AttributeName: "timestamp",
        AttributeType: "S"
        }
    ],
    KeySchema: [
        {
        AttributeName: "barname",
        KeyType: "HASH"
        },
        {
        AttributeName: "timestamp",
        KeyType: "RANGE"
        }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    },
    TableName: tableName
};
```

I put with two objects:

```
data1 = {
    barname: "paul",
    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    sync: false,
    number : "1234",
}

data2 = {
    barname: "john",
    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    sync: true,
    number : "333",
}
```

How to scan all objects that barname = 'john' and sync = true ?

I tried something like that:

```
var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    FilterExpression: "sync = :sync and barname = :barname",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':barname' : {S: 'john'},
        ':sync' : {BOOL: true}
      },
  };

  dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data){ ... }
```

The scan doesn't find anything:

> { Items: [], Count: 0, ScannedCount: 4 }

But i have 2 objects that match:

[image]

Comment: Also provide `ExpressionAttributeValues` for `sync` value.

Comment: I updated the code. I got the error: MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params
* InvalidParameterType: Expected params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':sync'] to be a structure

Comment: `':sync' : {BOOL: true}`

Comment: Oh sorry. Now i get this error:  UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params

Comment: Use `FilterExpression ` instead.

Comment: Hi, Now i have no errors. But the scan doesn't find any object. I updated the code.

Comment: I fix the problem using var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are using the `DynamoDB.DocumentClient`, but you are specifying the full attribute type in the filter expression. If you just change the expression to not include the type it should work. I won't go into why this is probably a bad idea (scanning).

```js
var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    FilterExpression: "sync = :sync and barname = :barname",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':barname' : 'john',
        ':sync' : true
      },
  };

  dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data){ ... }
```