# Function scan in DynamoDB doesn't bring some of the results

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I got a function in AWS Lambda that lists every patient in a table from DynamoDB. I realized that some items from the table were not on the list. This is my function to list:

```
module.exports.listPatients = async (event) => {
  try {
    const queryString = {
      limit: 5,
      ...event.queryStringParameters,
    };

    const { limit, next, name } = queryString;

    const localParams = {
      ...patientsParams,
      Limit: limit,
      FilterExpression: "contains(full_name, :full_name)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":full_name": name },
    };

    if (next) {
      localParams.ExclusiveStartKey = {
        id: next,
      };
    }

    const data = await dynamoDb.scan(localParams).promise();
    const nextToken = data.LastEvaluatedKey ? data.LastEvaluatedKey.id : "";

    const result = {
      items: data.Items,
      next_token: nextToken,
    };

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: ", error);
    return {
      statusCode: error.statusCode ? error.statusCode : 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        error: error.name ? error.name : "Exception",
        message: error.message ? error.message : "Unknown error",
      }),
    };
  }
};
```

Am I missing something?

I tried with and without a limit, removed the filters, and yet nothing.
I tested one of the ids with get() to test with the server can find one of those who are missing, and it worked.
I am using Serverless to deploy the code, and when I try offline, it's working.
Stackoverflow recommended this post when writing my question, but I am using DynamoDB.DocumentClient without specifying the full attribute type in the filter expression:
[How to scan in DynamoDB without primary sort key with Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067320/how-to-scan-in-dynamodb-without-primary-sort-key-with-nodejs)

Comment: What is `patientsParams`? Also, I would start this debugging effort with no filters and no limits, get the code to work returning all of the table's items first, and only then add filters and limits (if a limit is strictly needed). If you can't do a paginated scan and get all of the items returned then you (or the client) are misusing the ExclusiveStartKey  and/or LastEvaluatedKey somehow.

Comment: @jarmod You were right about `ExclusiveStartKey` when I removed it from the function, the scan brought everything. So now, I will test with the rest of the parameters. Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem was with the variable `next` which came as a string in the API call. So even when it came as **false**, it was entering the **if** statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are paginating using `scan()`. Using `query()` with some Global Secondary Indexes and `ScanIndexForward` would give you a much better performance. `scan()` doesn't scale well when your data grows.